# New book parser

Tags: python, beginner, parsing

I know that this is a complete mess and does not even come close to fitting PEP8.  That's why I'm posting it here.  I need help making it better.

```
bookName      = None
authorName    = None
bookStartLine = None
bookEndLine   = None

def New_book(object):
    def __init__(self, currentBookName, currentAuthorName, currentBookStartLine, currentBookEndLine):
        self.currentBookName      = currentBookName
        self.currentAuthorName    = currentAuthorName
        self.currentBookStartLine = currentBookStartLine
        self.currentBookEndLine   = currentBookEndLine
import urllib.request

def parser(currentUrl): #parses texts to extract their title, author, begginning line and end line
    global bookName
    global authorName
    global bookStartLine
    global bookEndLine
    global url

    url = 'http://www.gutenberg.org/cache/epub/1232/pg1232.txt' #machiaveli
    url = currentUrl    
    book = urllib.request.urlopen(url)
    lines = book.readlines()
    book.close()

    finalLines = [line.decode()[:-2] for line in lines]


    for line in finalLines:
        if "Title" in line:
            currentBookName = line[7:len(line)]
            break
    for line in finalLines:
        if "Author" in line:
            currentAuthorName = line[8:len(line)]
            break
    currentBookStartLine,currentBookEndLine = False,False

    for index,line in enumerate(line,start=1):
        if "*** START OF THE PROJECT" in line:
            currentBookStartLine = index

        if "*** END OF THE PROJECT" in line:
            currentBookEndLine = index



    url           = currentUrl
    bookName      = currentBookName
    authorName    = currentAuthorName
    bookStartLine = currentBookStartLine
    bookEndLine   = currentBookEndLine


parser('http://www.gutenberg.org/cache/epub/768/pg768.txt') #wuthering heights
print(url)
print(bookName)
print(authorName)
print(bookStartLine)
print(bookEndLine)
```

Comment: `I know that this is a complete mess`. If you know something is a complete mess I'm sure you have a reason to think so. Focus on the why and try to change it.

Answer (score 2):

- No need for a New_Book class with something so simple – I recommend a [named tuple](http://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.namedtuple) instead.
- HTTPResponse objects don't seem to have a readlines() method (in Python 3) – this forces you to explicitly split the response data with '\r\n'.
- It's best to use the with-statement for file/resource operations. This is a CYA in case you forget to include resource.close() in your code.

Here's my refactor:

```
from urllib.request import urlopen
import collections

def parser(url): 
    '''parses texts to extract their title, author, begginning line and end line'''

    with urlopen(url) as res:
        lines = res.read().decode('utf-8').split('\r\n')

    title = next(line[7:] for line in lines if line.startswith("Title: "))
    author = next(line[8:] for line in lines if line.startswith("Author: "))
    start,end = False,False

    for index,line in enumerate(lines,start=1):
        if line.startswith("*** START OF THIS PROJECT"):
            start = index

        if line.startswith("*** END OF THIS PROJECT"):
            end = index - 1

    content = "".join(lines[start:end])

    return collections.namedtuple('Book', ['title', 'author', 'content', 'start', 'end'])(title, author, content, start, end)

book = parser('http://www.gutenberg.org/cache/epub/1232/pg1232.txt' ) #machiaveli <3
print("{} by {}. {} lines".format(book.title,book.author,book.end-book.start))
#print(book.content)
```